# Show a popup when swiped from Left to Right in a ViewPager and during the popup page should not be moved

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have one `MainActivity`, holding 10 fragments. I would like to disable swiping from Right to Left in specific pages and show a popup instead, with cancel and Confirm buttons, where clicking confirm will take you to next fragment. I achieved this with OnTouch Implementation in `MainActivity`. But the fragment is moving before popup is being generated. I have tried a lot in other answers in Stackoverflow, but no luck. Does `dispatchTouchEvent()`, `OnTouchIntercept()`, `OnTouchEvent()` help?

This is OnTouch method implemented for viewpager.

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int action = event.getActionMasked();
            float finalX;
            float finalY;
            switch (action) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = event.getX();
                    initialY = event.getY();
                    //Log.i(TAG, "Action was DOWN");
                    return true;

                /*case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //Log.i(TAG, "Action was MOVE");
                    finalX = event.getX();
                    finalY = event.getY();

                    if (initialX > finalX) {
                        //Log.i(TAG, "Left to Right swipe performed");
                        return true;
                    }
                    else return false;*/

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                    finalX = event.getX();
                    finalY = event.getY();

                    //Log.i(TAG, "Action was UP");

                    if (initialX < finalX) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Left to Right swipe performed");
                        return false;
                        //mViewPager2.setCurrentItem(mViewPager2.getCurrentItem()-1);
                    }

                    if (initialX > finalX) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Right to Left swipe performed");
                        int a = mViewPager2.getCurrentItem();
                        if(a==0||a==1||a==2||a==4||a==6){
                            displayPopup();
                            return true;
                        }
                        else if(a==7 && screenPreferences.getInt("user_login",0) == 0){
                            displayPopup();
                            return true;
                        }
                        else return false;

                    }

                    if (initialY < finalY) {
                        //Log.i(TAG, "Up to Down swipe performed");
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (initialY > finalY) {
                        //Log.i(TAG, "Down to Up swipe performed");
                        return true;
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    //Log.i(TAG,"Action was CANCEL");
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                    //Log.i(TAG, "Movement occurred outside bounds of current screen element");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to disable swiping from Right to Left in specific pages

YOu can use custom `ViewPager` to do this, use method `setPagingEnabled` to disable/enable swipe

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public AHBottomNavigationViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Enable or disable the swipe navigation
     * @param enabled
     */
    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Because you successfully detect your swiping, you can apply you code to show popup in the state disable swiping of viewpager to show popup, and you control click confirm/cancel of popup to set next your fragment.

Comment: Thank you. It worked finally. With the code and clue you have given, I had tried for the last time and it worked. OMG